# Import Matterport's Mask-RCNN model from github - error:ZipImportError: bad local file header

Tags: deep-learning

I try import Matterport's Mask-RCNN model from github, but I got an error. What did I wrong?

```
# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'Mask_RCNN'))  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
from mrcnn.model import log
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZipImportError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-19fc18cf001a> in <module>
      4 from mrcnn import utils
      5 import mrcnn.model as modellib
----> 6 from mrcnn import visualize
      7 from mrcnn.model import log

ZipImportError: bad local file header: '/home/wojtek/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mask_rcnn-2.1-py3.6.egg'
```

Answer (score 6):

1) You have to clone

> $ git clone https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.git

2) Install dependencies

> $ pip install -r requirements.txt

3) Run setup from the repository root directory

> $ python3 setup.py install