# NameError: name 'KE' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, faster-rcnn

I am following this tutorial: https://blog.paperspace.com/mask-r-cnn-in-tensorflow-2-0/ in order to train a custom dataset for object detection. When I run the code for training (under paragraph: "Train Mask R-CNN in TensorFlow 1.0"), I get this error on colab:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-794112aa6465> in <module>()
      6 import mrcnn.config
      7 
----> 8 import mrcnn.model
      9 
     10 class KangarooDataset(mrcnn.utils.Dataset):

/content/drive/MyDrive/How_to_Train_an_Object_Detection_Model_with_Keras/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py in <module>()
    255 
    256 
--> 257 class ProposalLayer(KE.Layer):
    258     """Receives anchor scores and selects a subset to pass as proposals
    259     to the second stage. Filtering is done based on anchor scores and

NameError: name 'KE' is not defined
```

After searching I tried to check that RCNN is ok with this: [Import Matterport's Mask-RCNN model from github - error:ZipImportError: bad local file header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378668/import-matterports-mask-rcnn-model-from-github-errorzipimporterror-bad-loca) with the solution that the guy in the end suggests. I have also found this: [NameError: name 'K' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275534/nameerror-name-k-is-not-defined) so I tried this command:

```
from keras import backend as KE
```

(instead of `K`, I put `KE`) but it didn't work!

Do you have any idea how to fix that error?

Comment: did you fix the import in Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You said you fixed the import (replacing `K` with `KE`) but where did you do that?

Comment: Inside `model.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried this github repository instead the original MaskRCNN: https://github.com/akTwelve/Mask_RCNN with the latest tensorflow (2.7.0) + Keras (2.7.0) installed on colab. It seems to overcome the above problem I described...I do not know why..!